# Bootstrap searchable dropdown list with multiple selection of countries with flags

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, semantic-ui

I am following this example in Semantic UI to create dropdown list of countries with flags, the selected countries will be displaced as tags.

As you see in this [example](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/examples) in 'Examples' section and 'search selection' part.
[image]

I have been searching for long for similar searchable dropdown list with multiple selection of countries with flags on Bootstrap but I found just simple dropdown list with one selection and any search or tags as you see in this [example](http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/country.html)

I am trying to avoid this semantic ui because when I add it to my bootstrap project it's causing naming conflit in some parts.

So my question, did you anyone did this searchable dropdown list with multiple selection of countries with flags in Bootstrap ? If yes, could you please guide me ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**[Select2](https://select2.org/)** should work fine for you. You can add cusom elements in `data` object.

Comment: i have checked Select2 it contains searchable dropdown list but without countries' flags. I need similar to the one in mentioned in semantic ui